# Postgresql: How to optimize performance of a query which uses CTEs and has a jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, performance, json, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I'm querying through 3 joined tables and I'm using CTEs and flattering (converting jsonb to a tabbular form) one of the table's jsonb column then querying through that dynamically made table so I can calculate the individual data in that jsonb column.

Using this code:

```
WITH students_query AS (
    SELECT student_number, "examYear", school_name, subjects
    FROM students
    INNER JOIN schools ON students.school_id = schools.school_number
    INNER JOIN results ON results.id = students.subjects_id
    WHERE
        "examYear" = '2010'
        AND
        "examType" = 'CSEE'
), subjects_array AS (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(subjects) AS subject_list
    FROM students_query
), unwrapper AS (
    SELECT 
        x.*
        FROM subjects_array,
        jsonb_to_record(subject_list) AS x(
            subject varchar(25),
            grade varchar(2)
        )
), failures AS (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*)::numeric AS fails
        FROM unwrapper
        WHERE 
            "subject" = 'B/MATH' AND "grade" IN ('D', 'F', 'X')

), passes AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)::numeric AS passes
        FROM unwrapper
        WHERE
            "subject" = 'B/MATH' AND "grade" IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
), final AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)::numeric AS allStudents
        FROM unwrapper
        WHERE 
            "subject" = 'B/MATH'
)


SELECT 
    fails AS "Number of Fails",
    passes AS "Number of passes",
    allStudents AS "Number of All Students",
    ROUND((fails/allStudents *100), 2) AS "Percent of Fails",
    ROUND((passes/allStudents *100), 2) AS "Percent of Passes"
    FROM failures, passes, final;
```

**Problem** is slowness.

This particular query takes about 10 seconds to finish, But this is an important query and most users will be using it so I would love to optimize it.

**Steps I've made**

**Indexes:** I've made some indexes, but I'm not sure if they even do a thing.

```
drop index if exists fk_idx_results;
drop index if exists idx_results_subjects;
drop index if exists fk_idx_schools;
drop index if exists idx_schools_name;
drop index if exists fk_idx_students;

create index fk_idx_results on results("id");
create index idx_results_subjects on results("subjects", "examYear");

create index fk_idx_schools on schools("school_number");
create index idx_schools_name on schools("school_name");

create index fk_idx_students on students("id", "subjects_id", "school_id");
```

**Settings** I also appened some settings before the query which kinda got it to 9 seconds.

```
SET cpu_index_tuple_cost = .0005;
SET random_page_cost = 2;
```

**Ask** now I'm asking for help, I'm new to postgresql and the whole big database optimization.

Here is the `explain analyze` query report.

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=6330354.67..6330354.76 rows=1 width=160) (actual time=10103.862..10103.865 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  CTE students_query"
"    ->  Hash Join  (cost=390430.66..607236.38 rows=476181 width=347) (actual time=1378.337..3543.161 rows=458487 loops=1)"
"          Hash Cond: (students.school_id = schools.school_number)"
"          ->  Hash Join  (cost=390237.54..600495.77 rows=476181 width=326) (actual time=1376.496..3407.941 rows=458487 loops=1)"
"                Hash Cond: (students.subjects_id = results.id)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on students  (cost=0.00..93850.85 rows=4658285 width=36) (actual time=0.029..616.052 rows=4658285 loops=1)"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=362894.28..362894.28 rows=476181 width=340) (actual time=1375.636..1375.636 rows=458487 loops=1)"
"                      Buckets: 16384  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 2876kB"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on results  (cost=0.00..362894.28 rows=476181 width=340) (actual time=0.020..1187.420 rows=458487 loops=1)"
"                            Filter: (("examYear" = '2010'::text) AND ("examType" = 'CSEE'::text))"
"                            Rows Removed by Filter: 4199798"
"          ->  Hash  (cost=113.61..113.61 rows=6361 width=33) (actual time=1.831..1.831 rows=6361 loops=1)"
"                Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 469kB"
"                ->  Seq Scan on schools  (cost=0.00..113.61 rows=6361 width=33) (actual time=0.009..0.857 rows=6361 loops=1)"
"  CTE subjects_array"
"    ->  CTE Scan on students_query  (cost=0.00..246423.67 rows=47618100 width=32) (actual time=1378.350..4638.517 rows=3473367 loops=1)"
"  CTE unwrapper"
"    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1904724.00 rows=47618100 width=80) (actual time=1378.369..8489.830 rows=3473367 loops=1)"
"          ->  CTE Scan on subjects_array  (cost=0.00..952362.00 rows=47618100 width=32) (actual time=1378.351..5344.083 rows=3473367 loops=1)"
"          ->  Function Scan on jsonb_to_record x  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=80) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=3473367)"
"  CTE failures"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=1249984.05..1249984.07 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=9379.408..9379.409 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          ->  CTE Scan on unwrapper  (cost=0.00..1249975.13 rows=3571 width=0) (actual time=1378.423..9342.868 rows=387778 loops=1)"
"                Filter: (((subject)::text = 'B/MATH'::text) AND ((grade)::text = ANY ('{D,F,X}'::text[])))"
"                Rows Removed by Filter: 3085589"
"  CTE passes"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=1249984.05..1249984.07 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=365.217..365.217 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          ->  CTE Scan on unwrapper unwrapper_1  (cost=0.00..1249975.13 rows=3571 width=0) (actual time=0.093..363.892 rows=24002 loops=1)"
"                Filter: (((subject)::text = 'B/MATH'::text) AND ((grade)::text = ANY ('{A,B,C}'::text[])))"
"                Rows Removed by Filter: 3449365"
"  CTE final"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=1072002.48..1072002.49 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=359.222..359.222 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          ->  CTE Scan on unwrapper unwrapper_2  (cost=0.00..1071407.25 rows=238090 width=0) (actual time=0.005..339.228 rows=411822 loops=1)"
"                Filter: ((subject)::text = 'B/MATH'::text)"
"                Rows Removed by Filter: 3061545"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=9744.630..9744.632 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        ->  CTE Scan on failures  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=9379.410..9379.411 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        ->  CTE Scan on passes  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=365.219..365.220 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on final  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=359.224..359.225 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.546 ms"
"Execution time: 10186.026 ms"
```

**Additional Information**
Postgresql version: 9.6.1

The `results` table you can see above has about 4.6 Million rows which all contains the `subjects`::jsonb column which (I guess) makes a big difference there.

The `students` table has 4.6 Million (exactly like `results` table) rows, this is for all students whose subjects results are in the results table linked with `students.subjects_id`.

The `schools` table has 6323 rows, which are linked with `students` table at `schools.school_number = students.school_id`.

**Sample subjects** column output.

```
[{"grade": "D", "subject": "HIST"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "GEO"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "KISW"}, {"grade": "C", "subject": "ENGL"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "LIT ENG"}]
 [{"grade": "D", "subject": "CIV"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "GEO"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "KISW"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "ENGL"}]
 [{"grade": "C", "subject": "CIV"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "KISW"}, {"grade": "B", "subject": "ENGL"}, {"grade": "A", "subject": "CHEM"}, {"grade": "A", "subject": "BIO"}, {"grade": "B", "subject": "ENG SC"},{"grade": "C", "subject": "B/MATH"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "ELECT INST"}, {"grade": "D", "subject": "ELECT ENG SC"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "ELECT DRAUGHT"}]
 [{"grade": "F", "subject": "CIV"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "GEO"}, {"grade": "C", "subject": "E/D/KIISLAMU"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "KISW"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "ENGL"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "LIT ENG"}, {"grade": "C", "subject": "ARABIC"}]
 [{"grade": "F", "subject": "CIV"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "HIST"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "GEO"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "KISW"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "ENGL"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "BIO"}, {"grade": "F", "subject": "B/MATH"}]
```

Comment: Could add your Postgres version and how many rows your tables roughly have? Do you have the option to change the schema? Jsonb is very useful, but this case looks on first glance like it would fit better to a plain relational schema without a json column. If you use jsonb, you probably want to use the jsonb operators and functions instead of converting it to a table.

Comment: Is 4.6 = 460,000?

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you, I updated the question and I'm not sure exactly how I would approach the more normalized way of the `subjects` because more subjects vary so I appended a sample output of subjects jsonb column to show what I mean.

Comment: It's 4.6 Million, sorry let me update that. @JackDouglas.

Comment: @ArchNoob I'm not sure I understand your schema entirely, there are some weird aspects like students having as many rows as results, which indicates that a student appears multiple times in the students table. I would have used a students table, and exams table and a table linking them both in a many-to-many relationship. Subject would be a regular column on the exams table, as well as grade, year, etc.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm not sure if I also understand you correctly but yes. A student row appears multiple times, but it's because each student row is for a different student and that particular student has a `subjects_id` column which points to their subjects in `results` table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree your structure seems a little funny and not normalized. Your indexes aren't doing much but that is fixable. You probably want to index elements of the JSON like subject and grade.

Since that isn't a trivial subject to explain, you might want to check out this blog post where he walks through doing that with an example set:

http://bitnine.net/blog-postgresql/postgresql-internals-jsonb-type-and-its-indexes/?ckattempt=1

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I'm reading the blog post you referred to me but something more of a concern to me is why do you think the database structure is not normalized / funny looking? Have you read the last comment I made on my question above where I tried to explain why it's the way it is?

Comment: Thanks, Your answer participated on my research to get a clear question I should've asked. **How to search through an array of objects**. The blog post you shared didn't cover this which ignited the fire in my brain. I wish I upvoted your answer but I need more points. Hehe..

Comment: It is kind of tough to tell the schema from your post. Try building an example in SQLFiddle or RexTester.

Comment: You are right, my structure isn't normalized. I had to take a closer look to see it.. (New to most relational db concepts). I'm considering changing the implementation but it will take a while. Thank You, I'll post my progress (as another answer) when It's complete.

Comment: Feels good, Now that I have enough points to upvote this answer, It helped me in tough times. My table is normalized now and It's pretty fast.

Thank You :)